# How to use fullcalendar eventPositioned in angular 7?

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am trying to add background text and adjust event bar size based on the start and end date time. Can you please let me know how to use the event positioned? can you please share me syntax on how to add background text on events and adjust the event bar size.

** EXAMPLE:**

```
{
    title : '66666',
    start : '2019-04-14 12:30:00',
    end   : '2019-04-14 16:30:00',
    title:<top right corner> TEXT1,
    custom text2: time
}


@ViewChild('fullcalendar') fullcalendar: FullCalendarComponent;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.options = {
      editable: true,
      displayEventTime: false,
      fixedWeekCount: false,
      eventTextColor: 'white',
      height: 650,
      header: {
        left: 'prev',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'next'
      },
      events : [{
          title : '66666',
          start : '2019-04-14 12:30:00',
          end : '2019-04-14 16:30:00',
        },
        {
          title : '88888',
          start : '2019-04-07 07:30:00',
          end : '2019-04-07 20:30:00',
        }
      ],
      handleWindowResize: true,
      themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
      plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
      eventPositioned(info) {
        console.log(info);
      }

      <full-calendar #fullcalendar
        [events] ="options.events"
        [header]="options.header"
        [eventTextColor] ="options.eventTextColor"
        [height] ="options.height"
        [displayEventTime] ="options.displayEventTime"
        [themeSystem] = "options.themeSystem"
        [fixedWeekCount] = "options.fixedWeekCount"
        (dateClick)="dateClick($event)"
        [plugins]="options.plugins"
        (eventClick)="eventClick($event)"

      ></full-calendar>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
this.options = {

   eventPositioned: function(info){
        console.log("info of an event**strong text**",info);
      }
}
```